# Linq Query Count and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone tell me how to do this SQL Query in Linq?

```
SELECT [id], COUNT(*) FROM [data].[dbo].[MyTable] GROUP BY [id]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
 var res = ctx.MyTable  // Start with your table
    .GroupBy(r => r.id) / Group by the key of your choice
    .Select( g => new {Id = g.Key, Count = g.Count()}) // Create an anonymous type w/results
    .ToList(); // Convert the results to List
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I order that by Count?

Comment: @pirezas add `.OrderBy(v => v.Count)` between `Select` and `ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
var res = from r in MyTable 
          group p by r.id into grouped
          select new {id = g.key, total = g.Count()};
```

then, when you have to use it, just do `ToList()`
Also you can do it after the `select new`.
I don't have `Visual Studio 2010` here to try it, but 
I think it will work